# cannot download Android build-tools on Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to update the android sdk using filter feature. So far, I am having difficult time to download/update the build-tools. I had already make the

`buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"`

in `build.gradle` file in the project. As the build-tools is not part of the file I downloaded, running `android update sdk` is the only option I have.

Here is the script,

```
wget http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz
tar -xvf android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz

// using the following to check the available build-tools and I did saw 23.0.3

./android-sdk-linux/tools/android list sdk --all --extended


( sleep 5 && while [ 1 ]; do sleep 1; echo y; done ) | ./android-sdk-linux/tools/android update sdk --no-ui --filter tool,platform-tool,build-tools-23.0.3,platform,extra
echo sdk.dir=android-sdk-linux > local.properties



./gradlew assemble
./gradlew test --continue
```

The command gives me an error of

```
Error: Ignoring unknown package filter 'build-tools-23.0.3'
```

also

```
15:14:02 + ./gradlew assemble
15:14:03 
15:14:03 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
15:14:03 
15:14:03 * What went wrong:
15:14:03 A problem occurred configuring project ':MYPROJECT'.
15:14:03 > failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.3
```

When I change it to `build-tools-24.0.0` and I was able to download the build tools however, this is not the right build tool I need (I think 24 is for preview only), I am looking for a stable version. Can anyone please tell me how to download either `build-tools-23.0.1` or `build-tools-23.0.3` using the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to include --all in your update command. Otherwise the command ignores the older versions of the build tools. However you should run this separately from the other downloads so that you don't download all the platform-tools, all the platforms, all the tools, and all the extras. So you should call:

`./android-sdk-linux/tools/android update sdk --no-ui --filter tool,platform-tool,platform,extra`

and

`./android-sdk-linux/tools/android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-23.0.3`

each with your other logic that inputs 'y' to accept the licenses.